# laravel route resource with namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am trying to create a resource route in Laravel for my controller which is inside app\controllers\FormController. How can I do this? I tried in the following ways but none of them worked.

```
Router::resource('form', 'app\controllers\FormController');
Router::resource('form', 'app\\controllers\\FormController');
Router::resource('form', 'app/controllers/FormController');



namespace app\controllers;

class FormController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {


        return View::make('hello');
    }

}
```

If I remove the namespace, it works.

Result:

```
ReflectionException (-1) 
Class app\controllers\FormController does not exist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do the following:

```
Router::resource('form', 'FormController');
```

All classes in `app/controllers/` are automaticly loaded by Laravel.

**Update:**
You need to change the index function to `getIndex()`. If you use resource routing, every function has to start with the request method.

Comment: I updated my first post with the error. I used this resource: http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Comment: It worked. I had the BaseController under a different namespace

Answer (score 6):

`app/controllers` are loaded by default. but if you are using different namespace, you can use that.

e.g. namespace is `Site`;

```
Route::resource('form', '\Site\FormController');
```

there is another way.

let's say there are different controllers in the same namespace. e.g. `FormController`, 'BlogController`. you can *group* it.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Site'], function()
{
    Route::resource('form', 'FormController');
    Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
});
```

update #1:

```
Route::resource('form', 'FormController');
```

you don't need to use any namespace.

Comment: I tried both ways and none of them worked. I updated my first post